# Validation of uploaded Excel file before save using Rails with Roo-xls gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, validation, roo

In a model, before uploading an `.xls` file, I want to be able to validate excel files before they are saved by the application. I am trying to open the to-be-saved excel file from the `:file_url` object(column in comits table where the `.xls` files will be saved) and then validate it but I am getting a `no implicit conversion of Symbol into String` error.

The validation works when I place the actual file path of an excel file that has been uploaded and saved by carrierwave into `Roo::Excel.new("")` but that defeats the purpose of my validation.

How can I grab the excel file without it being stored in the application?

I appreciate the help! I hope is not too confusing.

This is my `comit.rb`

```
class Comit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  mount_uploader :file_url, ComitUploader, mount_on: :file_url
  validates :filename, :file_url, presence: true
  validates_format_of :file_url, with: /.xls/, message: "Wrong file format"
  before_save :validate_excel

  def validate_excel
    sheet = Roo::Excel.new(:file_url)
    errors = []

    header = sheet.row(1)
    num_of_columns = sheet.last_column

    errors << 'Need headers' unless
    errors << 'Need more columns' if num_of_columns < 21

    errors
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the symbol `:file_url` to `Roo::Excel.new`, it wants a path to the file.  Try:

```
sheet = Roo::Excel.new(file_url)
```

Comment: When I made this change, It still told me that there was no implicit conversion into a string. When I did file_url.to_s, it was able to find the correct path, however, I still get an error... but this time, though it finds the correct path, it now says that the file does not exist...

Comment: This worked after changing Roo::Excell to Roo::Spreadsheet and install the roo-xls gem. =] Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can send the **tempfile** to **Roo**.
Let's say you are sending the file to `params` as `:file`:

```
Roo::Excel.open(params[:file].tempfile.to_path.to_s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. Instead of `Roo::Excell`, it needs to be

```html
sheet = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(self.file_url)
```

Also, I needed to install the `gem 'roo-xls'` gem in order to read the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

In my case following code is working fine. (Assuming that you have installed required gems)**In my case I have the .xls file in my root directory**

```
require 'roo'
require 'roo-xls'
class ExcelReader
  def read_file()
  sheet = Roo::Spreadsheet.open('Test.xls')
  sheet.each do |row|
  puts row
end
 end
  obj=ExcelReader.new()
  obj.read_file()
 end
```