# Rails upload excel file, validate and save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, validation, file-upload

I am working on a rails engine that uploads a excel file, validates it and if there is no error than it will save it to database.

Now when ever a user mounts the engine and than go to the route provided by engine. He will have a form to upload the excel file. There are two buttons on page, i.e, `upload` and `validate`.

Once a user choose the file and when he click on upload i want that file only gets uploaded and don't get saved in db. Once i get the message the file is uploaded successfully, than i will validate the file. If it is a valid excel file with valid data than it will be saved into db. Now i am not getting how to go about it. I have seen this [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel) video on uploading `csv` and `excel` file but here he is performing validation and save operation with `import` action but i want validation and save operation when user clicks on `validate` action. [This Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31573319/validation-of-uploaded-excel-file-before-save-using-rails-with-roo-xls-gem) seems similar to my problem but i am not getting how do i access that uploaded file. I don't want that file to be saved in database. I mean when a user click on upload button that file gets only uploaded not saved. Than i will validate that file and save it's content to db.

This may seem very easy and simple questions for some experts but i am very new to rails and i am not sure how to go about it.

Someone please help me with a sample code, so that i can understand the workflow. Also note that both upload and validate actions are on same page. So when a file gets uploaded it needs to be stored somewhere temporarily, this is the first problem i am facing. I can do all the task if someone can tell me workflow with a sample code about uploading excel file. I am only having problem here that as both upload and validate action are on same page, so after upload request it needs to be on that page so that i can validate that file.

Any help would be appreciated, I am very beginner at rails and really confused here.

Answer (score 0):

**Two options:**

1. Write code to upload the file and save to DB with a `validated` column set to false.  Then the 'validate' button will locate the unvalidated file, validate it and set `validated` to `true`.  You could have a periodic job deleting unvalidated files of a certain age.  If you do this, use a helper gem like Paperclip.
2. Forego file upload frameworks and just manually save uploaded files to `Tempfile.new 'spreadsheet'`.  [This guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files) takes you through how to do that.  Save that filename to [session](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-rails-sessions-work/) and use it to validate at a later point.  When you're finally ready to persist to DB, again, consider using a helper gem.

Comment: actually solved the problem. I was getting confused, but that's done. thanks for reply.